# FTP Upload to other domain

Tags: php, upload, ftp

I have two domains. On the first one there is a file upload form which I want to add to the second domain. The point is that I must keep one FTP folder (which is on the first domain).

It looks like that:

> SERVER/domains/example.pl/FTP (I want my files to upload here)
>
> SERVER/domains/site2.pl/ (somewhere here will be second php upload
>   form)

Unfortunately, second site is on prestashop and I don't know where exactly script file will be kept (cms created content is in held in database).

Is there a way to create a direct patch to my upload folder, for example now in script I have:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/FTP/" . $d . "/"
```

and change it to:

```
$path = 'www.domain.pl/FTP/'
```

I was also thinkg about creating an iframe to the first form inside prestashop article and this way avoid the problem. But will it be functional?

Answer (score 0):

In both domain first print current directory using getcwd() function. Suppose you get var/www/domain1/ in first domain and var/www/domain2 in your second domain and suppose your upload folder be var/www/domain1/uploads then in this case you could use ../domain1/uploads in your second domain to upload those files in your first domain.